# Is "What a big like deserves this picture" correct?

Tags: grammar

While I was doing some facebook things, I shared a picture and this sentence came to my mind. I was wondering if it is correct to use this sentence when you want to share your feelings about something (in this case that picture):

> What a big like deserves this picture, doesn't it?

What I meant to say was:

> I think this picture deserves a big like, don't you?

If it's correct, could you please tell me about the detailed structure of the sentence? I just made it up and my mind naturally says it should be correct.

Comment: If what you meant to say was the second version, why didn't you just say that in the first place? The first version is grammatically gibberish.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't get the exact point of gibberish, but I'm just curious about the first one, actually about my mind reaction to the grammar! I just wanna know if it's correct or not. Some times breaking the roles is an interesting game! Cheers

Comment: If you're truly interested in "grammar", and in knowing whether a given form is "correct" or not, why not start by practising with words like **want to**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers What do you mean? using **wanna** instead of **want to**?

Comment: Yes. If you leave it like that someone will probably end up correcting it anyway. But surely you can see that on a site for [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq) it's not a particularly appropriate form?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. You know, I learned english all by myself, without having any teacher. I think these all are the consequences of self-studing!

Comment: @FumbleFingers not to be picky, but "wanna" is a grammatically correct word.  It's not formal, but like "ain't", it is neither incorrect nor un-grammatical.

Comment: Well in that case you're not doing too bad at all. But to get a sensible answer on this question you'd need to explain *why* you thought the first version would be valid. To be honest, I don't know whether *a big like* is "acceptable" anyway. It might be to Facebook/Twitter users, but it seems rather odd to me.

Comment: @Charles: It's perfectly acceptable in all but the most formal *spoken* contexts, but I for one don't think it's good enough for ELU question text.

Comment: @Mohammad, Luke: Following the edit I'm upvoting both the question and jlovegren's answer!

Comment: Oh my God!! What a good people you all are! really,, Thank you! @Charles Thank you about the tip. I didn't know "wanna" is grammatically correct but I did know that it's informal. So that's why I use it many times. FumbleFingers Thank you! You made my day! Just for noticing, in this question (as you already said) "like" was some facebook thing that depending on the environment, it's not odd to call it big or small! it's actually a button that shares your feeling. I was just curious about my mind reflex to the grammar I made up! Thank you all again.. Cheers

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think my question deserves a vote but I did upvote the answer. It was perfect! :D

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi Just because something is "grammatical" doesn't mean it's correct.  It depends if you're a descriptive linguist who just observes the use of language or a prescriptive linguist who sets language rules.  If you're learning English, listen to prescriptive linguists (who say that "wanna" is not a word), not the descriptive ones (who say "wanna" is a word because it's used and understood).

Comment: @Charles Thank you dear Charles. I got it. You are great! All of you. Cheers

Comment: Mohammad, you should consider supporting our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners). Lots of us "great" people plan to frequent that site when it becomes active. I think you'd have a lot to contribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the simple sentence:

```
[This picture].NP.sbj [deserves].V [a big like].NP.obj
```

The more complicated construction that the OP is trying to form is a case of object-fronting, so the object is "moved" with respect to the simpler sentence to the first linear position, and the original object slot is left empty:

```
  [What a big like].NP.obj [This picture].NP.sbj [deserves].V [ $\o$ ]
```

A number of constructions in English involve dislocating an object noun phrase to the beginning of the clause.

The first proposed sentence ("what a big like deserves this picture") additionally inverts the order of the subject noun phrase and the verb. In many languages where a subject noun phrase would normally precede the verb, e.g., Spanish, subjects may be emphasized, or focused, by dislocating them to appear either after the verb, or after the verb and the object. For example (in Spanish),

```
Vio una pelicula mi mama.
saw a   movie    my mother
"_My mother_ saw a movie."
```

To focus a subject in English, however, no such construction is available, whether in a main or a subordinate clause. So if in your native language you can be flexible about the placement of the subject NP, do not expect to have the same liberties with English.

Comment: Your answer was PERFECT! Thank you man. So my sentence is incorrect. Yeah?

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi yeah, the first one is incorrect.

Comment: I got disappointed in my mind reactions! :D By the way, thank you about the great answer.

Comment: Little Jack Horner has been getting away with ['What a good boy am I!'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Jack_Horner) for a long time now. Personally I don't think "question tags" really work after such "what" statements, but here's an example in print ['What a helpless woman you are, aren't you?'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22what+a+helpless+woman+you+are+aren't+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), so it can't be totally off the planet.

Comment: I think the first one you mentioned is like the one I asked in the question. Am I right? Also I'm so familiar with the second example.

Comment: Good point, @FumbleFingers. Actually subject-verb inversion works with [be] in English. i'm going to change the Spanish example.

Comment: @jlovegren So my first sentence was not that bad? Yeah?! ;D

Comment: @jlovegren: I think you're probably right that it only works with [be]. In some other contexts it often turns out that [have] and [be] allow more variability than other verbs, but I can't think of anything remotely akin to *"Grandma! What big teeth have you!"* that would be acceptable to the modern ear.

Comment: _What a big “Like” this picture deserves_ might read a little awkwardly, but I wouldn't deem it unacceptable. As for _What a big “Like” deserves this picture_, I say, heed the advice you've been given – I think you wanna fogettaboutit.

Comment: Wait, no one has a problem with 'like' as a noun? That's the biggest clunker/nonnativism of all!

Comment: @Mitch: I handled that "clunker" with quotation marks and capitalization. In the context of Facebook, I think "Like" can indeed be a noun, as in, _I got 15 "Likes" on my pictures last night!_

Comment: @J.R.: OK. so eventually it might be a word, but it really sounds wrong (especially in the inverted word order). The OP may have a facility with English, but I don't want him to think any of this will be easily understood by a native speaker.

Comment: @Mitch: I think you were right to point that out; using _like_ as a noun certainly adds to the awkwardness of the sentence. I made an effort to use _"Like"_ instead of _like_, and you took the time to mention the "clunker" explicitly. Nice teamwork?